# RxJava Single display alertdialog

Tags: android, rx-java3

I feel like maybe what I am trying to do is the wrong way to do it, maybe it just isn't possible, or maybe my Google searching is just using all the wrong terms.

In my android app, I have the following:

**Invoice Table**

```
@Entity(tableName = "invoice_table")
public class Invoice {
  @PrimaryKey
  @ColumnInfo(name = "Invoice_No", index = true)
  private int invoiceNo;

  @ColumnInfo(name = "Customer_Serial")
  private int customerSerial;

  @ColumnInfo(name = "Delivery_Status")
  private int deliveryStatus; /* 0 = Despatched, 1 = Receiving */

  public Invoice(int invoiceNo, int customerSerial, int deliveryStatus) {
    this.invoiceNo = invoiceNo;
    this.customerSerial = customerSerial;
    this.deliveryStatus = deliveryStatus;
  }

  public int getInvoiceNo() { return invoiceNo; }
  public int getCustomerSerial() { return customerSerial; }
  public int getDeliveryStatus() { return deliveryStatus; }

  public void setDeliveryStatus(int deliveryStatus) { this.deliveryStatus = deliveryStatus; }
}
```

**DAO**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM invoice_table WHERE Invoice_No = :invoiceNumber")
Single<Invoice> getInvByNum(int invoiceNumber);

@Update
void updateInvoice(Invoice... invoice);
```

**View Model**

```
public Single<Invoice> getInvByNum(int invoiceNumber) { 
  return dao.getInvByNum(invoiceNumber); 
}

public void updateInvoice(Invoice invoice) {
  dao.updateInvoice(invoice);
}
```

I have a single activity called **DeliveryDriverActivity**.

In this activity, I use fragments to determine whether I am showing the 'despatch' or 'receive' list.

A delivery driver scans the barcode on an invoice using their mobile handheld computer (with built-in barcode scanner) in the 'despatch' section, this works 100%, my recyclerview shows perfectly, etc...

Once they have finished scanning, they then go out on their delivery run, at a customers premises, they then go to the 'Receive' section which loads the receive fragment.

They then scan the first invoice for the customer, this sets the stage for what other invoices they can scan (Can only scan invoices for this particular customer).

In my receive fragment I have

**Receive Fragment**

```
private int mCustomerSerial;

Single<Invoice> invoiceSingle = viewModel.getInvByNum(barcode);
invoiceSingle.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .subscribe(invoice -> {
    int customerSerial = invoice.getCustomerSerial();

    if (invoice.getDeliveryStatus() == 1) {

    }

    if ( mCustomerSerial != 0 && customerSerial != mCustomerSerial ) {

    }

    mCustomerSerial = customerSerial;
    invoice.setDeliveryStatus(1);
    viewModel.updateInvoice(invoice);
  }, throwable -> Objects.requireNonNull(throwable.getMessage())));
```

When I scan the very first invoice, everything works perfectly, the delivery status is changed from 0 to 1 and the Room Table is updated perfectly.

If I scan a second invoice for the exact same customer, it all works perfectly too.

However, if I scan the same invoice number again, or, I scan an invoice for a completely different customer, I would like it to display an alertdialog informing the user that they did something wrong.

Just not sure what the best way about it is.

Answer (score 0):

Switched from Single to Maybe, mostly because I had an extra condition I wasn't testing for at all just yet.

Changed code to

```
viewModel.getInvByNum(barcode)
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .subscribe(new MaybeObserver<Invoice>() {
    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(@NonNull Invoice invoice) {
      int customerSerial = invoice.getCustomerSerial();

      if (invoice.getDeliveryStatus() == 1) {
        /* Display AlertDialog() */
      }

      if ( mCustomerSerial != 0 && customerSerial != mCustomerSerial ) {
        /* Display AlertDialog() */  
      }

      mCustomerSerial = customerSerial;
      invoice.setDeliveryStatus(1);
      viewModel.updateInvoice(invoice);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {

    }
  });
```

And now my alertdialogs show perfectly.